# document is not defined after running webpack scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, document, server-side-rendering

So I tried creating a boilerplate for an existing project that our company have and after running the script for webpack,
it generated a ./dist/server.js however, when I run it from node, I am getting this document not found error. Please let me know if you need a code snippet of a specific file.

**ERROR**

```
){var n=(0,r.renderToString)(o().createElement(Wn,null));a.send('\n  <!DOCTYPE html>\n  <html>\n    <head>\n    </head>\n    <body style="margin:0">\n      <div id="root">'+n+'</div>\n    </body>\n    <script src="main.bundle.js" defer><\/script>\n  </html>\n')})),Hn.listen(3e3,(function(){console.log("app listening on port 3000!")}))})()})();
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

*code above is a long one line code which I had to cut off*

**webpack.config.client.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.tsx',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        test: /\.(tsx|ts)?$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '/src/assets/images/[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        loader: "file-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/public'),
  },
};
```

**webpack.config.server.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const { join } = require('lodash');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    server: './server/index.tsx',
  },
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false,
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      title: "Test",
      template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(s*)css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
          },
          {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '/src/assets/images/[name].[ext]'
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
            loader: "file-loader"
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
          }
      ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```